# Convergence/divergence of a function of the first $n$ terms of a sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, analysis, convergence-divergence

Let $(x_n)$ be an arbitrary sequence in $\mathbb R$ and let $y_n=y_n(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ be a function which depends solely on the first $n$ terms of $x$. My question concerns the convergence and divergence of $(y_n)$.

Firstly consider the case that $y_n=\sqrt{x_1+\sqrt {x_2+\sqrt{\ldots+\sqrt{x_n}}}}$ and $x_n\geq 0$. Clearly, $y_n$ is an non-decreasing sequence. Also, if the sequences $(x_i^{(1)})_{i=1}^\infty, (x_i^{(2)})_{i=1}^\infty$ satisfies $\lim x_i^{(1)}/x_i^{(2)}<\infty$, then $y_n(x^{(1)})$ converges whenever $y_n(x_i^{(2)})$ converges.

The two sequences is said to have the same order of infinity (which is an equivalence relation) if $0<\lim x_i^{(1)}/x_i^{(2)}<\infty$. Define the set of orders of infinity to be the set of such equivalence classes of sequences. By using zorn's lemma in some way, I proved that there exist an order of infinity, represented by the sequence $c_n$, such that whenever $\lim x_n/c_n=0$, $y_n(x)$ converges, and  whenever $\lim x_n/c_n=\infty$, $y_n(x)$ diverges.

Now, the question is: **could I find the sequence $c_n$ explicitly?** Of course, the sequence $x_n=Ae^{2^nk}$ will fit into the square roots nicely, but this is clearly not satisfying the requirement of $c_n$.

Comment: What do you  mean "By using zorn's lemma in some way"?

Comment: @martycohen Well I am not writing it down because it is not directly related to what I am asking. My focus is on finding an explicit expression for $c_n$ rather than proving the existence. 

Informally speaking, to prove the existence of such $(c_n)$, consider pairs of orders of infinity of the form $([(a_n)],[(b_n)])$ ($[]$ represents equivalence classes), where $y_n$ diverges if $x_n/b_n\to infty$ and converges for $x_n/a_n=0$. Getting $a$ and $b$ "closer and closer" so that eventually they are the same. This uses Zorns lemma.